# How to make plt.pause() work if last open figure is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to create a bunch of matplotlib figures in my python 3 script. The script runs infinitely and plots things depending on the user's input. I need to use a plt.pause() in some of the script, since time.sleep() won't work in my case.

I seem to be having an issue, where the user can close any figure except for the last one that was created. Let's say, for example, that the user creates 3 figures. If the script is in the plt.pause, and the user closes Figure #1 or Figure #2, everything works as it should. However, if the user closes just Figure #3, the script crashes and i get an error: _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed

I need to use the tkagg back end because I am using tkinter.

Below is a short script that demonstrates the issue. You will come up with the error if the script is in the plt.pause() and you close the last created figure.

```
import matplotlib;
matplotlib.use("tkagg");
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

fig1 = plt.figure();
plt.pause(2);
plt.show(block=False);

fig2 = plt.figure();
plt.pause(2);
plt.show(block=False);

fig3 = plt.figure();
plt.pause(2);
plt.show(block=False);

input("done");
```

Is there any way so make it so that the plt.pause() is not dependent on just the last opened figure? maybe I can have a "fake" figure that is never shown that the plt.pause() uses?

Thanks

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: please, don't use `;` at the end of lines - Python doesn't need it and it looks awful.

Comment: as I know `show()` was created as simple method only to display image - ie. for debuging. For something more complex it may need to use directly `tkinter` and embeded plot in its window. But it can be more complex work.

Comment: This looks very much like a bug in matplotlib. You can open an issue at the issue tracker about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look how is `plt.pause()` implemented:

```
def pause(interval):
    manager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active()
        if manager is not None:
            canvas = manager.canvas
            if canvas.figure.stale:
                canvas.draw_idle()
            show(block=False)
            canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
        else:
            time.sleep(interval)
```

Hence each call of `plt.pause` starts event loop that lasts `interval` seconds and applies to all figures. This is undesired behaviour. Hovewer, it is possible to do the same with each figure individually using [close events handling](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/close_event.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
active_figures = {}

def handle_close(event):
    print('closed figure:', active_figures[event.canvas])
    event.canvas.stop_event_loop()

def create_figure(name):
    fig = plt.figure(name)
    active_figures[fig.canvas] = name
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)
    fig.show()  # it also uses block, it is False by default
    print(name, 'starts event loop')
    fig.canvas.start_event_loop(2)
    print(name, 'stops event loop')

for name in ['fig1', 'fig2', 'fig3']:
    create_figure(name)

print("\nmy figures:")
for n in active_figures:
    print('{} is opened: {}'.format(active_figures[n], plt.fignum_exists(active_figures[n])))
plt.show() #this keeps all the existing figures responsive to close
```